Not able to configure clerk webhook to sync with mongodb
I am trying to sync my clerk to MongoDB but I've not been able to do it. In the clerk dashboard it is showing as failed. Please refer to the screenshots.

middleware.js:
import { authMiddleware } from "@clerk/nextjs";

export default authMiddleware({
  publicRoutes: ["/"],
  ignoredRoutes: ["/api/webhooks(.)"],
});

export const config = {
  matcher: ["/((?!.\..|_next).)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};


Relevant Images:




I think authMiddleware is deprecated.
try const { clerkMiddleware} = require("@clerk/nextjs/server");
